# while (mysql_fetch_array) in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code:

```
while ($sum<16 || $sum>18){
$totala = 0;
$totalb = 0;
$totalc = 0;
$ranka = mysql_query("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE rank=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$rankb = mysql_query("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE rank=2 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$rankc = mysql_query("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE rank=3 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ranka)) {
    echo $rowa['duration'] . "<br/>";
    $totala = $totala + $rowa['duration'];
}
while ($rowb = mysql_fetch_array($rankb)) {
        $totalb = $totalb + $rowb['duration'];      
    }       
while ($rowc = mysql_fetch_array($rankc)) {
        $totalc = $totalc + $rowc['duration'];
    }

    $sum=$totala+$totalb+$totalc;
}
echo $sum;
```

It works fine, But the problem is until "$sum=16" the "echo $rowa['duration']" executes, the question is, is there a away to "echo" only the latest executed code in the "while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ranka))" i this while loop?
Because most of the times returns all the numbers until the "$sum=16"

Comment: What do yo mean by `only the latest executed code`?

Comment: Thanks Vidit, Keeyai answered my question. you can check the answer to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly echoing the $rowa['duration'] in the first inner while loop. If you only want to print the last duration from the $ranka set, simple change the echo to `$rowa_duration = $rowa['duration']` then echo it outside the loop.

```
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ranka)) {
    $rowa_duration = $rowa['duration'];
    $totala = $totala + $rowa['duration'];
}
echo $rowa_duration . '<br/>';
```

Comment: What if there was more than one "duration"? let's say if this line was like that   "$ranka = mysql_query("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE rank=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");"

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you wanting to print all the durations again, the same as your problem you initially posted?

Comment: no, If you taked a look in the code i have a "rand" function soo it's searches in the database until find thoes clips that the sum of ther durations equals to a number (any number), so some times i want 2 clips from rank 1 or 2 clips from ranks 3. and i want to print ther durations.

Comment: What i really want is to print the latest executed "while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ranka)) {
    echo $rowa['duration'];
}" outside the parent while loop.

Comment: The rand in your ORDER BY clause only means the row returned is randomly selected from the table. As for your last comment, if you want the echo outside the parent loop, simply move the echo there - the $rowa_duration variable will still be available at the end.

Comment: I know that, but it works only if i had one duration, maybe i could do it just with "$rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ranka)" without the "while" loop, but sometimes i nedd more than one ot two, that's why i have added "while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($ranka))", So what i want is if my query was like that "("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE rank=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");" which it should output 3 durations becuse the "LIMIT =3"

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing there is bad on multiple levels. And your english horrid. Well .. practice makes perfect. You could try joining ##php chat room on FreeNode server. That would improve both your english and php skills .. it sure helped me a lot. Anyway ..

### The SQL

First of all, to use `ORDER BY RAND()` is extremely ignorant (at best). As your tables begin the get larger, this operation will make your queries slower. It has `n * log2(n)` complexity, which means that selecting querying table with 1000 entries will take ~3000 times longer then querying table with 10 entries.

To learn more about it , you should read [this blog post](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/), but as for your current queries , the solution would look like:

```
SELECT duration 
FROM table 
    JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)) AS id) as choice
WHERE 
    table.id >= choice.id
    rank = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

This would select random `duration` from the table.

But since you you are actually selecting data with 3 different ranks ( 1, 2 and 3 ), it would make sense to create a UNION of three queries :

```
SELECT duration 
FROM table 
    JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)) AS id) as choice
WHERE 
    table.id >= choice.id
    rank = 1 
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT duration 
FROM table 
    JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)) AS id) as choice
WHERE 
    table.id >= choice.id
    rank = 2 
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT duration 
FROM table 
    JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)) AS id) as choice
WHERE 
    table.id >= choice.id
    rank = 3 
LIMIT 1
```

Look scary, but it actually will be faster then what you are currently using, and the result will be three entries from `duration` column.

### PHP with SQL

1. You are still using the old `mysql_*` functions to access database. This form of API is more then 10 years old and should not be used, when writing new code. The old functions are not maintained (fixed and/or improved ) anymore and even community has begun the [process of deprecating](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) said functions.

   Instead you should be using either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Which one to use depends on your personal preferences and what is actually available to you. I prefer PDO (because of named parameters and support for other RDBMS), but that's somewhat subjective choice.
2. Other issue with you php/mysql code is that you seem to pointlessly loop thought items. Your queries have `LIMIT 1`, which means that there will be only one row. No point in making a loop.
3. There is potential for endless loop if maximum value for `duration` is `1`. At the start of loop you will have `$sum === 15` which fits the first `while` condition. And at the end that loop you can have `$sum === 18` , which satisfies the second loop condition ... and then it is off to the infinity and your SQL server chokes.

And if you are using fractions for `duration`, then the total value of 3 new results needs to be even smaller. Just over `2`. Start with `15.99` , ends with `18.01` (that's additional `2.02` in duration or less the `0.7` per each). Again .. endless loop.

### Suggestion

Here is how i would do it:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost', 'username', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$sum = 0;
while ( $sum < 16 )
{
    $query = 'that LARGE query above';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare( $query );
    if ( $statement->execute() )
    {
        $data = $statement->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        $sum += $data[0]['duration']+$data[1]['duration']+$data[2]['duration'];
    }
}
echo $data[0]['duration'];
```

This should do what your code did .. or at least, what i assume, was your intentions.

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to tell you how this application works, I know my english is bad but i will try my best. or if it's ok for you i will send you the interface code too, And thanks for this great advices im already trying to learn PDO.

Comment: I don't really have the time to dig through unfamiliar code. You should just start with the first query ( the shorted one ) and rewrite it so that it works with you existing database. In your case the PDO is fairly minor thing. You can always migrate you code when it actually already works. If the basic algorithm does not change, then migration from `mysql_*` to prepares statements with PDO will actually count as optimization. Oh .. and read that blog post, which i mentioned.

Comment: It's HTML code jut to let you know how the application works, Because i think no one knows what i really want because of my bad english,. Anyway i'll folow your advices for sure. Thanks